# How to Configure Proxy in vue.config.js for API Requests in a Kubernetes Pod with Spring and Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kubernetes, cors, nuxt.js

I am running a Java Spring API and a Vue.js with Nuxt.js project in the same K8s container. The frontend is hosted on port 3000 while the backend is on port 8080. I aim to make an API request from the frontend to the backend without exposing the API to the public.

I need to fetch data from 'localhost:8080/api/v1/endpoint'. To achieve this, I have configured a proxy in my vue.config.js file as shown below:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a snippet of my Vue.js component to fetch from the API:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      response: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const apiUrl = '/api/v1/endpoint';

    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
          this.response = data;
          this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  },
};
</script>
```

When fetching from the API via my code I get following response:

```
{
  "url":"/api/v1/news/articles/user",
  "statusCode":404,
  "statusMessage":"Page not found: /api/v1/news/articles/user",
  "message":"Page not found: /api/v1/news/articles/user",
  "stack":""
}
```

In inspecting the network traffic and headers, I discovered that the requested URL is http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/v1/endpoint, and it seems my request is not being forwarded to port 8080.

Comment: you do know the proxy setting is only for develop mode, right?

Comment: I have relatively little experience with Vue.js and this is my first big project. I've only seen examples with proxy. What is the best way to deploy front and backend in the same container and still not get a problem with cors?

Comment: To not have issues with CORS, make sure your API server sends appropriate CORS headers to appropriate cross origin requests